# Can I take moldy melatonin pills?

Tags: medications, mold

I have melatonin pills that were stored in the bathroom for a while.

The expiration date is still valid, but they have some weird dots that look like mold. Can I still take them? Will they even work? Will it be detrimental to my health if I take them?

[image: moldy melatonin pills]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only are they moldy, it looks like they've also been damaged by moisture. See how the surface is rippled in spots? That's what water does to pills.

[Bathrooms are the worst place to store medicines because of the heat and humidity from showers and bathtubs.](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/patientinstructions/000534.htm)

No, the medicine is not safe to use despite being within the expiration date (see same link above). Although they might not hurt you ("might" being the key word), they are quite likely ineffective.